# jQuery Mobile buttons to fill the screen width

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Using jQueryMobile_1.4.5.css, I am trying to get the footer 3 buttons to fill the screen width but unable to find what property or tags to use to do that.
Thanks

```html
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <button type="submit" data-theme="c">NO</button>
    <button type="submit" data-theme="c">EXTRA</button>
    <button type="submit" data-theme="c">YES</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like buttons inside header and footer are displayed inline. You can override this behavior by adding this CSS rule:

```
.ui-footer button.ui-btn { display: block; width: 100%; }
```